# Entity Framework: Remove Both Directional Navigation when Scaffolding

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When I scaffold a database with Entity Framework Core, how do I prevent bidirectional properties ? I only want to allow 1 way unidirectional navigation. Is there a command line scaffold parameter?

In Product Class,I want to remove this property

```
public virtual ICollection<CustomerTransaction> CustomerTransaction { get; set; }
```

Basically only Customer Transaction should have Navigation, since it has the actual Foreign Key. Want to remove last line, and have similarly 1000+ table entities like this. Need EF scaffold command line parameter or automation (maybe with Regex or other tool).

**Database:**

```
create table dbo.CustomerTransaction(
    CustomerTransactionId int NOT NULL,
    ProductId int NULL,
    Quantity int NULL,
    CustomerLastName varchar(255) NULL,
    constraint PK_CustomerTransactionId primary key clustered (CustomerTransactionId ASC))

alter table dbo.CustomerTransaction add constraint fk_CustomerTransaction_Product_ProductId FOREIGN KEY(ProductId) REFERENCES dbo.Product (ProductId)
```

**Entity Framework:**

```
public partial class CustomerTransaction
{
    public int CustomerTransactionId { get; set; }
    public int? ProductId { get; set; }
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }
    public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }

    //Keep this line since it has the foreign key
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}


public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        CustomerTransaction = new HashSet<CustomerTransaction>();
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }

    // REMOVE THIS LINE
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerTransaction> CustomerTransaction { get; set; }
}
```

**Result:**

Only want this way available,

```
storeDbContext.CustomerTransaction.Include(c => c.Product).ToListAsync()
```

Not this way,

```
storeDbContext.Product.Include(c => c.CustomerTransaction).ToListAsync()
```

Using EF Core 2.2,

Comment: @GAltelino I have 1000 plus tables, looking for automated way to do this, thanks

Comment: hi @GertArnold i want the properties, but only want  them one way, this states it should be single direction, Domain driven design, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/396043/domain-driven-design-navigation-properties-and-aggregate

Comment: hi @GertArnold I want collection properties, just only one way, its just a company requirement, thanks

Comment: well we mapped our data layer to be pretty close to domain layer

Comment: hi @Pac0  just curious if Microsoft has an Entity Framework scaffold command line parameter, instead of creating custom regex, thanks

Comment: @DerrikRodgers agreed that that would surely make a better answer to your issue !